# How to create a javascript array from a SharePoint List?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'd like to convert a sharepoint list into an array where each dictionary in the array has all key values from a given sharepoint record.

I've tried the following:

```
function array_from_sharepoint_list(){
    var array = []
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Sharepoint_List')
    var caml = new SP.CamlQuery()
    caml.set_viewXML('')
    var listitems = list.getItems(caml)
    context.load(listitems,'Include(ID,Title,col_one,col_two)')
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,function(){
            var listEnumerator = listitems.getEnumerator();
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()){
                var list_item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                var item_dictionary = {ID:list_item.get_item('ID'),Title:list_item.get_item('Title'),col_one:list_item.get_item('col_one'),col_two:list_item.get_item('col_two')}
                array.push(item_dictionary)
            }
        },
        Function.createDelegate(this,function(){})))
    return array 
}
```

The result does not give me the array needed with every column from the sharepoint list, since it only pulls four columns and I do not know all the column names.

Comment: Mmm not sure if it is the same thing for you... or if it changes everytime... but I got something like that by doing something like this ```Object.keys(oListItem.get_objectData()["$1h_0"]["$m_dict"])``` the thing is that I'm not sure about the last 2 keys, If they change based on environments or calls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using REST API, with jQuery:

```
function array_from_sharepoint_list(ListName){
    var array = []
    var appWebUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

    $.ajax({
        url: appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('" + ListName + "')/items",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            array = data.d.results;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    return array 
}
```

REST API documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I need! By the way the variable ListName is throwing a variable error due to casing