# I Can't Get my Sharepoint list through the REST API in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to get my sharepoint list into an array but the console return me this:

> Demande.JS:66 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> at arrayFromSharepointList (Demande.JS:66:9)
> at Demande.JS:88:19

here is my code:

```
function arrayFromSharepointList()
    {
        var array = []
        var appWebUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

        $.ajax({
                    url: appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('MyList')/items",
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    headers:    
                        {
                            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                        },
                    success: function (data) 
                        {
                            array = data.d.results;
                        },
        
                    error: function (err) 
                        {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
        
                });
        return array;
    }
```

I used this as a reference: [How to create a javascript array from a SharePoint List?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828931/19298906)

I am new to Javascript but i really need a way to link my sharepoint list to a html form, if you don't have a solution for the above but have an alternative way to link html to sharepoint I'm also interested.

Comment: `$.ajax` is a reference to jQuery which it can't find.

Comment: Hi Andy, do i need to call a library to use it? I tried to read multiple comments about Sharepoint in Javascript but I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library that needs to be loaded _before_ your script so your script can use it. [There are a number of ways to approach that](https://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for the wrong library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this error because you are missing dependency of jQuery file which is required to use the `$.ajax`.

You can refer the jQuery file from CDN in your HTML file like below:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Or you can use it from CDN JS like:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**OR**

If you are adding this HTML file on SharePoint site pages using script editor or content editor web part, I will recommend you to download the jQuery file, upload it in your SharePoint library (prefer "Site Assets" library), then access it from there in your HTML file like:

Relative path of SharePoint site:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Absolute path of SharePoint site:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works fine now, I knew it had something to do with libraries but i was searching for the wrong one. You should add defer to the script if it's in the head so it loads after the HTML.